# A Hadith on the virtue of the Prophet's SAW death

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

I encountered this Hadith in a YouTube comment :

> حياتي خير لكم تحدثون ونحدث لكم، ووفاتي خير لكم تعرض علي أعمالكم ، فما رأيت من خير حمدت الله عليه، وما رأيت من شر استغفرت الله لكم
>
> "the Messenger of Allah (blessing and peace of Allah be upon him) said: "My living is good for you, for you will be told what is good and what is bad for you; and my death is good for you, for your deeds will be shown to me, then whatever I see of good, I will praise Allah for it, and whatever I see of bad, I will pray to Allah to forgive you""

The commenter fell short in typing the exact source. Can someone determine where it can be found? Is it authentic?

Comment: [مسند البزار](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12981/2331) translation of [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/296459/)

Comment: Jazak Allahu Khayran